# Why is it printing the location of a1 and not printing what a1 actually is

Tags: c++

Why is it printing the location of a1 and not printing what a1 actually is?
[image]

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: Alright I will keep it in mind for next time

Comment: Your image is difficult to read.  I can't copy your text in the image into my IDE.  Sorry, no further help from me.

Answer (score 2):

Because `box` is array. C++ doesn't know how to print arrays, so it converts the array into a pointer and prints that.

If you want to print an array, then write a loop.

Comment: Thank you, John. So just make a loop for board?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. It looks to me like you are trying to print a `box`, so you need to make a loop for `box` not `board`. But I'm not sure what you are really trying to do, all I can say is why your code printed an address. What did you want your code to print?

Comment: `board[0][0]` is a `box*` pointer, and `box` is itself a `char[4][6]` array. So, you need 2 more loops, 1 for each dimensions of the `box`.

Answer (score 1):

Your printing the starting location of `board[][]` by using a pointer of type `*[][]`.

Display the values of of your character array `a1[][]` using two loops:

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{ for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
     cout<< a1[i][j];
}
```